# JS Object search

Tags: javascript

I would like to search an objects values with a keyword and return an array of objects that contain the keyword in any of the values. For example, if I gave search value as true it should return me list of records that matches in array. Can someone help me on this.
Thanks in advance!

```
var obArr = [
    {
        "Name": "vR",
        "Phone": "090223902",
        "Email": "c@gma.ko",
        "AccountId": "7PHAAY",
        "Active__c": false,
        "index":2
    },
    {
        "Name": "ry",
        "Phone": "390223902",
        "Email": "cdy3@gma.ko",
        "AccountId": "7Xi5AAF",
        "Active__c": true,
        "index":4
    },
    {
        "Name": "r2",
        "Phone": "390223902",
        "Email": "cxs@gma.ko",
        "AccountId": "7Xi5AAF",
        "Active__c": true,
        "index":9
    }
];
```

I tried the following code but throwing me the error due to boolean value and number.

```
var dummy = [];

var SearchVal = "7Xi5AAF";

for(var i=0; i<obArr.length; i++) {
  for(key in obArr[i]) {
    if(obArr[i][key].indexOf(SearchVal) != -1) {
      dummy.push(obArr[i]);
    }
  }
}
console.log(dummy);
```

> Error:- obArr[i][key].indexOf is not a function at Object.

Comment: Do you need to find substrings, or only exact matches? In your example, should it match `AccountId: "abc7Xi5AAFdef"`?

Comment: That's because you have a few non-string items in "value" side see `false`, `true`, `2`, `4`. Numbers and Booleans don't have an `indexOf` function. Convert them into string before use

Comment: I would like to find exact matches @Barmar if user search for “ 7Xi5AAF”, I would like to give all the objects list that match the search value.

Comment: Then use `===` instead of `indexOf()`

Comment: Can the search string be in any property, or are you only searching the `AccountId`?

Comment: you got me, it should be in any property. Due to number and Boolean the above code is failing. Thanks!